# text formatter that supports bullets

Tags: git, text-formatting

I am looking for a formatter to use with my git commits. `par` pretty much does what I want, with the (important) limitation that I can't get it to properly format bullet lists, which are pretty common in commit messages.

For instance:

```
% export PARINIT="rTbgqR B=.,?'_A_a_@ Q=_s>|"
% par << EOF                                                                                                                                            
heredoc> [JR-1234] This is a fix for the thing.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.

  - I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I also like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot.
  - I like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot. I am also a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
heredoc> EOF
```

This gives output:

```
[JR-1234] This is a fix for the thing.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.

  - I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I also like bullet
  - lists. I like bullet lists a lot.  I like bullet lists. I like
  - bullet lists a lot. I am also a developer that doesn't like
  - linebreaks.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
```

While, I would like to have something like this:

```
[JR-1234] This is a fix for the thing.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.

  - I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I also like bullet
    lists. I like bullet lists a lot.
  - I like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot. I am also a
    developer that doesn't like linebreaks.

I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
```

Doing this with `par` would be ideal, but some other standalone formatter
in the same vein would also do.

Comment: Good question. Some prefer two linebreaks between bullet points and in turn get better formatting for free. But like you I prefer “tight” bullet lists.

Comment: @Guildenstern Nice observation. Perhaps something like awk could be used to preprocess the input and insert linebreaks between bullets, and then postprocess output to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandoc will do that:

```
$ pandoc -t plain <<EOF
>  [JR-1234] This is a fix for the thing.
> 
> I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
> 
>   - I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I also like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot.
>   - I like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot. I am also a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
> 
> I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn't like linebreaks.
> EOF
[JR-1234] This is a fix for the thing.

I am a developer that doesn’t like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn’t like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn’t like linebreaks.

-   I am a developer that doesn’t like linebreaks. I also like bullet
    lists. I like bullet lists a lot.
-   I like bullet lists. I like bullet lists a lot. I am also a
    developer that doesn’t like linebreaks.

I am a developer that doesn’t like linebreaks. I am a developer that
doesn’t like linebreaks. I am a developer that doesn’t like linebreaks.
```

Comment: That's what I also ended up using shortly after posting the question. Since we aim for plaintext, I also disabled the smart extension so that quotes are preserved as ascii characters: `pandoc -f markdown-smart -t plain`